# Reading JSON into Python / Pandas - getting JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have data that has a few columns in json, but I need to convert each column to multiple columns within a Pandas dataframe (so each new column is a key, and each row will be the value associated with it for that row).

I created this function:

```
def convert_json_columns(df):
    cat_df = df['category'].apply(json.loads)
    cat_df = pd.DataFrame(cat_df.tolist()).add_prefix('category_')
    return pd.merge(df, cat_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

It worked for 2/5 columns, but json.loads() was throwing me an error for the others I was converting, saying it expected a ',':

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 30 (char 29)

I thought I would try to manually convert this column to a dictionary instead, as the json seemed valid (I pasted it into this tool [here](https://jsonlint.com/) and it said it was valid code). I can't paste it here because it has personal information.

So I attempted to convert it to a python dictionary by replacing "null" with "None", and everything else seemed like it should convert over fine. Once that was done I could convert the string to a dictionary pretty easily. E.g.:

From:

```
{"id":101531536,"name":null,"is_registered":null,"chosen_currency":null}
```

to:

```
{"id":101531536,"name":None,"is_registered":None,"chosen_currency":None}
```

However, I then realized that there was a value that had double quotes inside the string, and each value uses double quotes. I.e.:

```
test_dict = {"id":1635201695,"name":"John "Cowboy" Smith"} ##fake name
```

So I have two questions:

- is there a way to convert only the double quotes that are within a value in this string to single quotes, so it can then be converted to a dictionary?
- could this double quote within a value string be what's causing the json error? I am pretty new to python and completely new to json

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the cause of the JSON issue but you can easily replace double quotes with singles in pandas like so:

`df["column name"] = df["column name"].str.replace('"', "'")`